# What is the advantage of using a stable sort algorithm vrs an unstable sort using the original index to resolve ties?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Stable sort algorithms are slower than unstable sorts.  As an example [golang](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Stable) uses `O(n*log(n)*log(n))` calls to swap elements.

If our goal is to preserve the original order of the elements, why not just number them all (`O(n)`) then do an unstable sort (`O(n*log(n))`) using the original index to resolve instances where comparisons are equal.

This seems faster.

i.e. `O(n) + O(n*log(n)) < O(n*log(n)*log(n))`

Is this correct? 
Are there any reasons to prefer a stable sort?

Comment: Sure, you could number everything. At a cost of O(n) time *and* O(n) extra memory.

Answer (score 2):

Except for cache effects, stable sorts are generally *faster* than unstable sorts when they are allowed to use extra memory.

The stable sort you link to from golang does not use extra space, so it has to use a slower algorithm.  When it's important not to use extra memory, unstable sorts are used instead, because they're almost as fast in most cases and don't require it.

If you have to allocate extra memory for indexes, though, then you might as well use a fast stable sort instead.  There are lots of ways to do it in O(N log N) time using the same amount of extra space.

Comment: For clarity, when you say stable and unstable in the first paragraph, are you just talking about the case where the original order needs to be preserved or in the general case?

Comment: A stable sort (usually MergeSort) preserves the original ordering of elements that compare equal.  An unstable sort (e.g. QuickSort) does not.

Comment: Maybe I missed something.  

How can a stable sort be faster than an unstable sort?  The only difference is an extra requirement.

Comment: Yes, the answer is not correct. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability .. And when could be important to have stable sorting - imagine you are looking for some statistic data in your browser. Data change from time to time, therefore browser sorts it. However I decided to show user according whether they are registered or not.  If browser sort the data unstable algorithm, the order of rows could change after each sort. Is it ok? (The other possibility is add some other "hidden" criteria, after required.

Comment: @Robert As I said, stable sorts that use extra memory, like MergeSort, are generally faster than unstable sorts that do not.  They have the extra requirement to be stable, but they do NOT have the requirement to work without extra space

Comment: Python's TimSort manages to be both fast *and* stable.  Don't know how much extra memory it uses though.

Answer (score 1):

Intro sort (quick sort + heap sort so worst case time complexity is O(n log(n)) on two arrays (original data + indexes to original data) will take longer than merge sort (on a single array), which wouldn't need to sort original data + an array of indexes.

Unstable quicksort is only about 15% faster than merge sort. Sorting two arrays at the same time would make it slower than merge sort. The main disadvantage of merge sort is that it uses a second array. On a processor with 16 registers, such as X86 in 64 bit mode, a 4-way merge sort is about as fast as quicksort.